# how to prevent ABPeoplePickerNavigationController from automatically dismissing a presented view

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"testTitle"
                                      message:@"test"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];


UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"User clicked button called %@",action.title);

                           }];
UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"User clicked button called %@",action.title);

                               }];

[alertController addAction:okAction];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After selecting a property, the Alert will show up for a second then dismisses itself.

How can I prevent ABP from dismissing my alert?
OR
How can I use another event to bring my alert up to the user.

Comment: the hacky solution I have now is bad.  
`UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [peoplePicker presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    /* end of fake stuff */
    
    [peoplePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [peoplePicker presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];`

Comment: A solution was recommended to me

Basically use a selector
`[self performSelector:@selector(displayTheseAlerts) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];`